# How do you loop through disparate control-selected cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script that would normalize the selected phone numbers in a Google spreadsheet:

```
/**
 * Normalizes phone numbers to ###-###-#### format.
 */
function normalizePhoneNumbers() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = activeSheet.getActiveRange();
  var selectedCells = activeRange.getValues();

  var phoneNumber = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedCells.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < selectedCells[i].length; j++) {
      phoneNumber = selectedCells[i][j]; // for better readability

      if (phoneNumber) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); // remove all non-digit characters from phone number
      } else {
        continue;
      }

      if (phoneNumber.length === 10) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0, 3) + '-' + phoneNumber.slice(3, 6) + '-' + phoneNumber.slice(6, 10); 
      } else {
        continue;
      }

      selectedCells[i][j] = phoneNumber;
    }
  }

  activeRange.setValues(selectedCells);
};
```

This works when I select a row or a column or a block of cells, but only changes one of the items if I control-select cells scattered around the spreadsheet. Is it possible to change multiple cells in a non-contiguous selection? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not exactly possible. For instance, `activerange.setValues()` expects a single 2D array (like what's returned by `Range.getValues()`). In either case your function could only get a single rectangular array of data, not a disjoint set of cells, hen you call `getValues()`.

However, if you can deal with making this a custom function which is invoked within a spreadsheet (using something like `=NORMALIZEPHONENUMBERS`) then you can use `map()` as demonstrated under [Optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization) in the custom functions documentation.

Comment: i actually started by doing the custom function approach, but then i realized that i would have to call the function in one cell, but reference the phone number from another cell :-p. i just want the numbers normalized in place, so that's why i veered away from the custom function.

Comment: Maybe a sane way to handle this, then, would be to highlight the **entire** area which contains your to-be-formatted phone numbers, and have a regexp which decides, cell-by-cell, whether there is a number which it knows how to change.

Comment: ya, i think that's what my code is trying to do right now, unless you see something that i'm missing. so it's not essential that i get control-selected cells to work, it just would've been nice :-p.

Comment: Your code is calling getActiveRange(). To my understanding that function only returns a single rectangular range, which is usually the last one you edited or selected. So I'm a bit confused -- if I'm right, the call won't include anything but the last range you control-selected. If I'm wrong, then your original code **should** do what you described in the post.